# System.FormatException: The JSON value is not in a supported DateTimeOffset format

Tags: c#, json, .net, datetimeoffset, system.text.json

I was reading this MSDocs article about DateTime-related format support
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support#support-for-the-iso-8601-12019-format

And I was trying to play around just to figure out that the default configuration wasn't working as expected or I must be missing something out.

I mean:

```cs
DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-03-17T12:03:14+0000");
```

Works just fine.

BUT

```cs
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestType>(@"{ ""CreationDate"": ""2021-03-17T12:03:14+0000"" }");
```

Doesn't.

Example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace CSharpPlayground
{
    public record TestType(DateTimeOffset CreationDate);
    
    public static class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var dto = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2021-03-17T12:03:14+0000");
            Console.WriteLine(dto);

            var testType = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestType>(@"{ ""CreationDate"": ""2021-03-17T12:03:14+0000"" }");
            Console.WriteLine(testType.CreationDate);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception below is thrown:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to CSharpPlayground.TestType. Path: $.CreationDate | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 44.
 ---> System.FormatException: The JSON value is not in a supported DateTimeOffset format.
```

Comment: Please do not put tags in your question titles (the tagging help section is pretty explicit about this, and goes as far as listing exampel formats you shouldn't use).

Comment: I expect the issue is with +0000, with the expected value being +00:00. I can't advise how to solve this since I'm not really familiar with System.Text.Json, but it might involve writing a custom converter. I found a GitHub issue relating to this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31138)

Comment: @Llama thanks for pointing this out, and sorry.

Comment: FYI, when you are using hyphens and colons in the timestamp, ISO 8601 calls that the "extended" format, and that also *requires* a colon in the offset component.  The "basic" format doesn't use hyphens or colons in *any* of the components.  Mixing the two is not allowed by the spec, so your string as shown here is not ISO 8601 compliant.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint FYI this comes from a PSP I have to deal and I didn't get to decide how they are implementing their APIs... Also it's far from being the only thing off. And I have no say on which PSP I have to use at work. "Voila"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Implementing custon JSON behaviours with `System.Text.Json` is usually done with custom converters. Unfortunately there aren't many provided out the box for different date formats, so if you need to deserialise something not in the default `ISO 8601-1:2019` format you need to roll your own.

Forutnately that's not very difficult:

```cs
   using System.Text.Json;
   using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

    public class DateTimeOffsetConverterUsingDateTimeParse : JsonConverter<DateTimeOffset >
    {
        public override DateTimeOffset Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            Debug.Assert(typeToConvert == typeof(DateTimeOffset));
            return DateTimeOffset .Parse(reader.GetString());
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTimeOffset  value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString());
        }
    }
```

This way you'll the same behaviour you do when you use `DateTimeOffset.Parse()`.

You can use it like this

```cs
    public record TestType(DateTimeOffset CreationDate);
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
            options.Converters.Add(new DateTimeOffsetConverterUsingDateTimeParse());
            
            var testType = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TestType>(@"{ ""CreationDate"": ""2021-03-17T12:03:14+0000"" }",options);
            Console.WriteLine(testType.CreationDate);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh thanks, I thought the format I was trying to parse was part of the standard, my bad. Thanks again for your answer, really appreciated!

Comment: Good answer, but there is a bug in your Write method. Should be:

    
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTimeOffset  value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("O"));
        }